# Prove by induction that for $n\geq 3$, $p_1 \to p_2, p_2 \to p_3, \dots p_{n-1} \to p_n \implies p_1 \to p_n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have proven the base case for $n=3$ by creating a truth table and verifying the implication.
Now i need help with inducing a proof for every case. Please guide me on how i should approach this problem.

Comment: For a formal proof of such a statement, you should first try to give a formal definition of "$\ldots$"

Comment: Broadly speaking, the rest of the proof has two steps.  First use the _induction hypothesis_ to show $p(1)\to p(n-1)$.  Then use the _base case $(n=3)$_ to conclude that $p(1)\to p(n)$.  The first of these steps is where you have to contend with Hagen's point.

Comment: @brianMoehring i have already proven the base case of n=3 using a truth table. do i use another truth table for the induction???

Comment: If your comment is to my second step, I said to use your base case, not prove it.  Truth tables probably are useless for the inductive step.  Do you have experience with inductive proofs?

Comment: @BrianMoehring yes i have some experience with basic inductive proofs that involve algebra but i have never done one like this. I am assuming it is like this.... p1->p2, p2->p3,p(k-1)->pk=>p1->pk. let p(k-1) = p3 since we know p1->p3  prove p1->p4.

Comment: i am completely stuck my brain cannot handle this please help

Comment: I am assuming it is just what i have said above then you say p1->p3,p(k-1)->pk so p1->pk

Comment: Someone please help?

Comment: see below for a summary of induction plus an example of how it is done. These proofs are not generally done with truth tables. They are performed using the rules of inference in tandem with the axioms, theorems and definitions present in mathematics. I would be able to give you better direction if I knew what the statement actually was that you are trying to prove.

Comment: if you're satisfied with you're answer, then please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The induction step is to prove that

p1 → p2, p2 → p3, ..., p(n-1) → pn ⇒ p1 → pn
implies
p1 → p2, p2 → p3, ..., p(n-1) → pn, pn → p(n+1) ⇒ p1 → p(n+1).

First assume
p1 → p2, p2 → p3, ..., p(n-1) → pn ⇒ p1 → pn.

Now assume 
p1 → p2, p2 → p3, ..., p(n-1) → pn, pn → p(n+1).

Show from those assumptions that p1 → pn
and subsequently p1 → p(n+1).

Pull it together to conclude
p1 → p2, p2 → p3, ..., p(n-1) → pn, pn → p(n+1) ⇒ p1 → p(n+1)

and finally the induction step.

Forget about that truth table stuff.
It is not a major part of logic.
The rules of inference are.
Use them.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by induction is typically used to prove a statement about the natural numbers, or some subset thereof. For example, we may be proving $\forall n P(n)$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $P(n)$ is the statement $\sum_{i=0}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. In other words, we may be proving that for every $n \ge 0$, the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Proof by induction is organized into two steps:

$(1)$ In the **basis step**, you demonstrate that $P(n)$ is true for the least element in the domain you're working with. In the example above, we would want to show that $P(0)$ is true. So we work out $P(0)$, or $\sum_{i=0}^0i=0=\frac{0(0+1)}{2}=0$, and confirm that it is in fact true.

$(2)$ In the **inductive step**, the goal is to validly deduce the following statement: $P(k) \rightarrow P(k+1)$ where $k$ is some arbitrary number from the domain you're working with. This is typically accomplished by assuming the antecedent is true and then deriving the consequent. In other words, we assume that $P(k)$ is true, and then under that assumption we attempt to show that $P(k+1)$ is true.

Following the example above, I would assume $P(k)$, or $\sum_{i=0}^ki=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, is a true statement, and then my goal would be to derive $P(k+1)$, which is $\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}i=\frac{(k+1)[(k+1)+1]}{2}=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$. I would do all this as follows:

$$P(k): \sum_{i=0}^ki = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^ki + (k+1)= \frac{k(k+1)}{2} + (k+1)$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}i= \frac{k(k+1)}{2} + \frac{2(k+1)}{2}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}i= \frac{k(k+1)+2(k+1)}{2}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}i= \frac{k^2 +k+2k+2}{2}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}i= \frac{k^2 +3k+2}{2}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}i= \frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$$
$$P(k+1): \sum_{i=0}^{k+1}i= \frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$$

Once you have completed the basis step and the inductive step, you are finished. By induction you may conclude that $\forall n P(n)$ is true (i.e. $P(n)$ is true for all $n$ in the domain you're working with). This is all possible because the inductive step shows that *if* the statement $P(n)$ is true for any arbitrary number $k$ in your domain, then it is also true for the *very next number*, $k+1$. Since in the basis step you show $P(n)$ is true for the first number in the domain, this infers that $P(n)$ is true for every number after the first number.